# Ordenar una lista en todas sus formas posibles en Python

Tags: python

Quiero hacer un generador que ordene una lista que puede ser de cualquier longitud de todas las formas posibles en Python.
Tengo hecho un código; por ejemplo, para ordenar una lista de longitud 4, lo he hecho así:

```
for w in lista:
    for x in lista:
        if x == w:
            continue
        for y in lista:
            if y == w or y == x:
                continue
            for z in lista:
                if z == w or z == x or z == y:
                    continue
                print (w, x, y, z)
```

El problema me surge porque esta lista podría ser de cualquier longitud; imagino que debería meter un código similar dentro de un bucle `while` que se repita el número de veces de longitud la lista o algo similar...
Por otra parte supongo que existe alguna función de Python que haga esto, pero no he encontrado nada...

Comment: Casi seguro que existe una funcion de python.. y existen montones de algoritmos de orden (sort) desperdigados por todo internet... No se, cual es la pregunta....

Comment: Por favor, si quieres implementar un algoritmo, revisa algunos [algoritmos de ordenamiento](https://eiposgrados.com/blog-python/tipos-de-algoritmos-de-ordenacion-en-python/) o bien utiliza [funciones predefinidas](https://docs.python.org/es/3/howto/sorting.html) para ordenar como el método de las listas `sort` o la función `sorted`.

Comment: Te invito a revisar documentación sobre algoritmos de ordenamiento, te van a simplificar la vida con este tipo de problemas, un saludo bro.

Comment: `...ordenar una lista de longitud 4...` Python no es como C/C++ donde defines el número de elementos de un vector o usas malloc. En Python las listas pueden tener la longitud que aguante la memoria del equipo. Solo es aplicarle un algoritmo de ordenamiento y listo. Y Python ya trae incorporados [métodos para ordenar](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html).

Comment: Lo que buscas se llama "permutaciones" y no ordenaciones. Efectivamente tienes una fución python que te lo da: `for caso in itertools.permutations(lista): print(caso)`. Pero cuidado! A medida que la lista crece el número de las permutaciones se dispara. SI la lista tiene N elementos, tendrás N! (factorial de N) casos.

Comment: Estaba esperando la respuesta de @abulafia en tres líneas (contando el `import itertools`.

Answer (score 0):

Una solución rebuscada, *generando* código para ser ejecutado:

```
def permutar(lista):
    n = len(lista)
    fill = ''
    code  = f"lista = {lista}\n"
    code += f"n = len(lista)\n"
    code += f"i = [0] * n\n"
    for i in range(n):
        code+= fill + f"for i[{i}] in range(n):\n"
        fill += ' '
    code += fill + f"presentes = [j for j in range(n) if j in i]\n"
    code += fill + f"if len(presentes) == n:\n"
    code += fill + ' print(' + ','.join([f"lista[i[{j}]]" for j in range(n)]) + ')'
    return code
```

La función *genera* el código siguiendo el estilo propuesto por el OP:

- La lista `i` contiene el valor actual de la variable de control de cada `for`.
- Tenemos *n* `if` anidados; en el más interno, chequeamos que no haya indices repetidos creando una lista con los indices actuales y verificando que tenga tantos elementos como la lista `i`. En tal caso, imprimimos.

Se entendera mejor al mirar el código generado.

La función retorna un string con el código, el que ejecutamos con `exec()`.

#### Demo

```
test = list("abcd")
code = permutar(test)
print("El código generado:\n")
print(code)
print()
print("El codigo ejecutado:\n")
exec(code)
```

produce:

```
El código generado:

lista = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
n = len(lista)
i = [0] * n
for i[0] in range(n):
 for i[1] in range(n):
  for i[2] in range(n):
   for i[3] in range(n):
    presentes = [j for j in range(n) if j in i]
    if len(presentes) == n:
     print(lista[i[0]],lista[i[1]],lista[i[2]],lista[i[3]])

El codigo ejecutado:

a b c d
a b d c
a c b d
a c d b
a d b c
a d c b
b a c d
b a d c
b c a d
b c d a
b d a c
b d c a
c a b d
c a d b
c b a d
c b d a
c d a b
c d b a
d a b c
d a c b
d b a c
d b c a
d c a b
d c b a

Process finished with exit code 0
```